# how to change the values of drop down select option on the base of other

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two input fields, the values are coming through database. I want one user change the value of one input field, the second one change automatically based upon the value of first. I am using ajax, so far i have following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxfunction(parent)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'process.php?parent=' + parent,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#sub").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select onchange="ajaxfunction(this.value)">
<?php 
$q= mysql_query("select * from tab1");
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($q)){
$name= $row['name'];    
echo '

<option> '.$name.' </option>
';
}
?>
</select>
<select id="sub"></select>

</select>
</body>
</html>
```

and my process.php file is:

```
<?php

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `contents` WHERE `parent` = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["parent"]));
    while(($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== false)
        echo '<option value="', $data['id'],'">', $data['name'],'</option>'
?>
```

where i am doing wrong, I am even not getting the value of (parent). anyone help me please.

Regards

Comment: any console errors?, i hope you connect to the db in  process.php

Comment: alert(data); and check further

Comment: yes db is connect, no error in console

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: i am not geting the value of parent variable. first i need to get the value of parent variable .

Comment: Check your error log. Also, look in to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Answer (score 0):

add `value` attribute to option tag and try:

```
<select onchange="ajaxfunction(this.value)">
<?php 
$q= mysql_query("select * from tab1");
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($q)){
$name= $row['name'];    
echo '

<option value="'.$name.'"> '.$name.' </option>
';
}
?>
</select>
```

process.php

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `contents` WHERE `parent` = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["parent"]));
while(($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== false){
   echo '<option value="', $data['id'],'">', $data['name'],'</option>';
}
```

Comment: I should work either way. If no value is set in an option tag, the text will be used instead.

Comment: i write in process.php ($e =$_GET['parent']; echo $e;) but it show no result which means value is not getting out there

Comment: did you get alert(parent) value inside function ajaxfunction(parent) ?

Comment: is there any other library i have to include or change in ajax script required??

Comment: check echo $_GET['parent']; is getting by comment all other lines in process.php

Comment: in your process.php semicolon `;` is missing after `echo '<option value="', $data['id'],'">', $data['name'],'</option>'`